# How can I identify three highest values in a column by ID and take their squares and then add them in SAS?

Tags: arrays, sas

I am working on injury severity scores (ISS) and my dataset has these four columns: ID, High_AIS, Dxcode (diagnosis code), ISS_bodyregion.  Each ID/case has several values for "dxcode" and respective High_AIS and ISS_bodyregion - which means each ID/case has multiple injuries in different body regions. The rule to calculate ISS specifies that we have to select AIS values of *three different ISS body regions*

For some IDs, we have only one value (of course when a person only has single injury and one associated dxcode and AIS). My goal is to calculate ISS (ranges from 0-75) and in order to do this, I want to tell SAS the following things:

1. Select three largest AIS values by ID (of course when ID has more than 3 values for AIS), take their squares and add them to get ISS.
2. If ID has only one injury  and that has the AIS = 6, the ISS will automatically be equal to 75 (regardless of the injuries elsewhere).
3. If ID has less than 3 AIS values (for example, 5th ID has only two AIS values: 0 and 1), then consider only two, square them and add them, as we do not have third severely ISS body region for this ID.
4. If ID has only 3 AIS (for example, 1,0,0) then consider only three, square them and add them even if it is ISS=1.
5. If ID has all the injuries and AIS values equal to 0 (for example: 0,0) then ISS will equal to 0.
6. If ID has multiple injuries, and AIS values are: 2,2,1,1,1 and ISS_bodyregion = 5,5,6,6,6. Then we see that ISS_bodyregion repeats itself, the instructions suggest that we only select highest AIS value of ISS body region only *once*, because it has to be from DIFFERENT ISS body regions. So, in such situation, I want to tell SAS that if ISS_bodyregion repeats itself, only select the one with highest AIS value and leave the rest.

I am so confused as I am telling SAS to keep account of all these aforementioned considerations and I cannot seem to put them all in a single code. Thank you so much in advance. I have already sorted my data by ID descending high_AIS.

Comment: what does `If max (of ais [*]) > 5 then ISS =75;` means?

Comment: This means that the value of Injury severity score (ISS) has to be 75 if the max AIS value by ID is 6 (>5 represents 6 in this code).

Comment: Why bother to define an ARRAY if you are only going to use it to reference one variable?  Do you even have the three highest scores on a single observation?  Please show example values for one or two cases and the expected ISS score for that sample data.

Comment: The second largest value from an array with only one variable is always going to be missing since there can only be one value in one variable.

Comment: Here are the example values of the data I have:

Comment: Are you trying to calculate this score?  https://aci.health.nsw.gov.au/networks/institute-of-trauma-and-injury-management/data/injury-scoring/injury_severity_score  If so then you also need to have grouped the injuries by body system so that you take the highest AIS per body system first and then take the highest three per case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you are trying to implement this algorithm https://aci.health.nsw.gov.au/networks/institute-of-trauma-and-injury-management/data/injury-scoring/injury_severity_score then you need data like this:

```
data have;
  input id region :$20. ais ;
cards;
1 HEAD/NECK   4 
1 HEAD/NECK   3
1 FACE        1 
1 CHEST       2 
1 ABDOMEN     2
1 EXTREMITIES 3
1 EXTERNAL    1
2 ABDOMEN     3
3 FACE        1
3 CHEST       2
4 HEAD/NECK   6
;
```

So first find the max per id per region.  For example by using PROC SUMMARY.

```
proc summary data=have nway;
  class id region;
  var ais;
  output out=bodysys max=ais;
run;
```

Now order by ID and AIS

```
proc sort data=bodysys ;
  by id ais ;
run;
```

Now you can process by ID and accumulate the AIS scores into an array.  You can use MOD() function to cycle through the array so that the last three observations per ID will be the values left in the array (skips the need to first subset to three observations per ID).

```
data want;
  do count=0 by 1 until(last.id);
    set bodysys;
    by id;
    array x[3] ais1-ais3 ;
    x[1+mod(count,3)] = ais;
  end;
  iss=0;
  if ais>5 then iss=75;
  else do count=1 to 3 ;
    iss + x[count]**2;
  end;
  keep id ais1-ais3 iss ;
run;
```

Result:

```
Obs    id    ais1    ais2    ais3    iss

 1      1      2       3       4      29
 2      2      3       .       .       9
 3      3      1       2       .       5
 4      4      6       .       .      75
```

Comment: Please update your original quesiton with examples of the data you have.  If you have only one observation per ID then that would explain why there is only one top value.  As to what to do when you have less than three observations that is for you to decide.  What is the source of the current formula?  What do they recommend you do when there are less than three observations?

Comment: Thank you. I am new on Stackoverflow and kind of struggling with how to upload a picture of the my dataset. But let me update my original question with all the information. Thank you so much for your responses. It means a lot

Comment: Do not load data has photographs, they are impossible to code with.  Just show the data as a simple data step.  For example by using in-line data and INPUT statements.

Comment: See updated answer that includes example data using the case from the website plus some other cases with fewer injuries.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I followed your instructions and I got the result! I cannot believe I am almost there. Thank you so much.